# CONFIG_SOMETHING on vendor/phone_defconfig won't work, have to pass them on `make`

Tags: kernel, compiling, make

On https://github.com/MoonBase-Project/MSM-4.19-MiBengal/ I had to do

```
make CONFIG_HAVE_KVM=y CONFIG_KVM=y CONFIG_KVM_ARM_HOST=y O=out ARCH=arm64 CC=clang CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- vendor/citrus-perf_defconfig
make CONFIG_HAVE_KVM=y CONFIG_KVM=y CONFIG_KVM_ARM_HOST=y O=out ARCH=arm64 CC=clang CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- -j$(nproc --all) 2>&1 | tee kernel.log
```

because putting

```
CONFIG_HAVE_KVM=y 
CONFIG_KVM=y 
CONFIG_KVM_ARM_HOST=y
```

on `vendor/citrus-perf_defconfig` wouldn't work no matter what I tried. The `.config` generated from it wouldn't have the KVM configs.

Also I tried to print:

```
$(info ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ KVM)
$(info $$CONFIG_KVM_ARM_HOST is [${CONFIG_KVM_ARM_HOST}])
```

but it was empty, except when passed on `make`

What is happening?